# Why is `set PATH=0;%PATH% && echo %PATH%` printing the old environment?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

For a problem I try to solve I wanted to update the environment variable and write it to a file in the same call but I realized that following call still prints the old environment:

```
set PATH=0;%PATH% && echo %PATH%
```

Is there a reason why and is there a way to update the environment and save it to a file in 1 call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason why. Command is a per-line interpreter. It simply does not support what you ask of it.